Checkbox Uncheck does not refresh table in Vue
I am using Daisy UI and simple VUE and working on a checkbox. When I check the checkbox it fitlers the table entries and works fine but when I uncheck or check another checkbox it does not refresh/filter again.
The following is my table component:


import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import currencyHelpers from '../lib/currencyHelpers';

const info = ref({});
const currencies = ref([]);
const headers = [
  { title: 'Name' },
  { title: 'ID' },
  { title: 'ID rego fee' },
  { title: 'ID import fee' },
  { title: 'Converter Name' },
  { title: 'Proof Protocol' },
  { title: 'Options' }
];
const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 'OPTION_FRACTIONAL' },
  { value: 2, label: 'OPTION_ID_ISSUANCE' },
  { value: 4, label: 'OPTION_ID_STAKING' },
  { value: 8, label: 'OPTION_ID_REFERRALS' },
  { value: 16, label: 'OPTION_ID_REFERRALREQUIRED' },
  { value: 32, label: 'OPTION_TOKEN' },
  { value: 128, label: 'OPTION_GATEWAY' },
  { value: 256, label: 'OPTION_PBAAS' },
  { value: 512, label: 'OPTION_PBAAS_CONVERTER' }
];
const selectedCurrency = ref(null);
const currencyDetails = ref('');
const selectedOptions = ref([]); // Array to store selected options

const handleCurrencyClick = (currency) => {
  console.log(currency.currencydefinition.currencyid)
  const fullyQualifiedName = currency.currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname;
  console.log("Clicked currency:", fullyQualifiedName);
  selectedCurrency.value = currency;
};

// Function to filter currencies based on selected options
const filterCurrencies = () => {
  if (selectedOptions.value.length === 0) {
    return currencies.value; // Return all currencies if no options are selected
  }

  return currencies.value.filter(currency => {
    return selectedOptions.value.every(option => {
      // Check if the currency has the selected option
      return (currency.currencydefinition.options & option) !== 0;
    });
  });
};

onMounted(async () => {
  info.value = await currencyHelpers.getInfo();
  currencies.value = await currencyHelpers.listCurrencies();
});

// Watch for changes in selectedOptions and filter currencies accordingly
watch(selectedOptions, () => {
  currencies.value = filterCurrencies();
});
<template>
  <div class="overflow-x-auto columns-1">
    <div class="collapse collapse-arrow bg-base-200">
      <input type="checkbox" /> 
      <div class="collapse-title text-xl font-medium">
         Filter Currencies
      </div>
  <div class="collapse-content"> 
      <div class="form-control border mt-1 pt-1">
          <label v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
           <input type="checkbox" :value="option.value" class="checkbox checkbox-primary" v-model="selectedOptions"> <span class="label-text">{{ option.label }}</span>
          </label>
      </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header.title">{{ header.title }}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="hover" v-for="currency in currencies" :key="currency.currencydefinition.currencyid">
            <td @click="handleCurrencyClick(currency)">{{ currency.currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname }}</td>
            <td>{{ currency.currencydefinition.currencyid }}</td>
            <td>{{ currency.currencydefinition.idregistrationfees }}</td>
            <td>{{ currency.currencydefinition.idimportfees }}</td>
            <td>{{ currency.currencydefinition.gatewayconvertername }}</td>
            <td>{{ currency.currencydefinition.proofprotocol }}</td>
            <td>{{ currency.currencydefinition.options }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div v-if="selectedCurrency">
      <h2>Selected Currency Details</h2>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="50">{{ selectedCurrency }}</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>



The above uses simple vue/html components. I have removed vuetify completely from my project because I am using Daisy UI classes to style my components.
The data I am getting from currencyHelpers Library is getting data from a TS library. The options is an attribute in the return response of what is getting displayed in table.

You can't have the same v-model attached to multiple checkboxes.

How I built the logic
In the absence of adequate data for proper reproduction, I created a simplified example.
In my code, you can choose options from 1 to 10. If none is selected, all currencies will be displayed. However, if at least one option is selected, only items selected from currencies will be displayed. I implemented this functionality with filtering similar to your code and overriding the displayed array with a listener.
In order not to lose the data of the original currencies after the override, I stored them in a separate array called defaultCurrencies.
Missing defaultCurrencies, Overwriting original data (Solution)
Your logic fails at this point. You download the data of currencies in the onMounted hook. After that, every time you change the selectedOptions, it (currencies) will be overwritten, so after the first overwrite, the original data will be lost and only the filtered values will remain. Therefore, when you remove the filters, you cannot return to the original array because it is missing.
const defaultCurrencies = ref([]) // HERE
const currencies = ref([])

const filterCurrencies = () => {
  if (selectedOptions.value.length === 0) {
    return defaultCurrencies.value // HERE
  }

  return defaultCurrencies.value.filter(currency => {
    return selectedOptions.value.every(option => {
      return (currency.currencydefinition.options & option) !== 0
    })
  }) // HERE
}

onMounted(async () => {
  info.value = await currencyHelpers.getInfo()
  defaultCurrencies.value = await currencyHelpers.listCurrencies() // HERE
})

currencies.value = filterCurrencies()
watch(selectedOptions, () => {
  currencies.value = filterCurrencies()
})

Example # 1 (with watch as you mentioned)


const { createApp, ref, watch } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const options = ref([
      { value: 1, label: '1' },
      { value: 2, label: '2' },
      { value: 3, label: '3' },
      { value: 4, label: '4' },
      { value: 5, label: '5' },
      { value: 6, label: '6' },
      { value: 7, label: '7' },
      { value: 8, label: '8' },
      { value: 9, label: '9' },
      { value: 10, label: '10' },
    ])
    const selectedOptions = ref([])
    
    // The original data of the array must be handled separately from the array of displayed data
    const defaultCurrencies = [
      { id: 1, name: 'First' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Second' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Third' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Fourth' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Fifth' },
      { id: 6, name: 'Sixth' },
      { id: 7, name: 'Seventh' },
      { id: 8, name: 'Eighth' },
      { id: 9, name: 'Ninth' },
      { id: 10, name: 'Tenth' },
    ]
    // Array of displayed data
    const currencies = ref([])
    // To modify the array of displayed data (currencies) by using defaultCurrencies
    const filterCurrencies = () => {
      if (selectedOptions.value.length === 0) {
        return defaultCurrencies
      }
      return defaultCurrencies.filter(currency => selectedOptions.value.includes(currency.id))
    }
    
    // watch
    currencies.value = filterCurrencies()
    watch(selectedOptions, () => {
      currencies.value = filterCurrencies()
    })
    
    return { options, selectedOptions, currencies }
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.23/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="option.value" v-model="selectedOptions">
    <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
  </span>
  
  <p>Selected: {{ selectedOptions }}</p>
  <div>
    <p v-for="(currency, index) in currencies" :key="currency.id">- {{ currency.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>



Example # 2 (with computed)


const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const options = ref([
      { value: 1, label: '1' },
      { value: 2, label: '2' },
      { value: 3, label: '3' },
      { value: 4, label: '4' },
      { value: 5, label: '5' },
      { value: 6, label: '6' },
      { value: 7, label: '7' },
      { value: 8, label: '8' },
      { value: 9, label: '9' },
      { value: 10, label: '10' },
    ])
    const selectedOptions = ref([])
    
    // The original data of the array must be handled separately from the array of displayed data
    const defaultCurrencies = [
      { id: 1, name: 'First' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Second' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Third' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Fourth' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Fifth' },
      { id: 6, name: 'Sixth' },
      { id: 7, name: 'Seventh' },
      { id: 8, name: 'Eighth' },
      { id: 9, name: 'Ninth' },
      { id: 10, name: 'Tenth' },
    ]
    // To modify the array of displayed data (currencies) by using defaultCurrencies
    const filterCurrencies = () => {
      if (selectedOptions.value.length === 0) {
        return defaultCurrencies
      }
      return defaultCurrencies.filter(currency => selectedOptions.value.includes(currency.id))
    }
    // Array of displayed data
    const currencies = computed(filterCurrencies)
    
    return { options, selectedOptions, currencies }
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.23/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="option.value" v-model="selectedOptions">
    <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
  </span>
  
  <p>Selected: {{ selectedOptions }}</p>
  <div>
    <p v-for="(currency, index) in currencies" :key="currency.id">- {{ currency.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>




Works fine I suppose but the problem is that the data table does not display data unless I filter anything
